# Is it possible to have different sitemaps for different robots?

Tags: sitemap-index

Is it possible to have different sitemaps for different robots? I could put **disallows** in the `robots.txt` file, but that is a lot of work.

Comment: Why would you need to have different sitemaps for different robots?

Comment: I am using some website checking sites in the free mode, where there is a limit to the urls.  If I could have a different sitemap for these, then I could put the modified pages in there, or even rotate the pages.

Comment: How do you submit the sitemap to these website checking sites?

Comment: Good point, unfortunately, They all take the url of the main page.

Comment: It sounds like they may not use the sitemap at all.  It sounds like they crawl links from the main page.

Comment: I will look at the logs next time I use their services